# Why is this pop() function creating a seg fault?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I have the class `stackLL` and the `pop()` function creates a seg fault when used in the main. Here's the code:

Here's the struct and class definitions:

```
struct llNode{
int data;
llNode* next;
};

class stackLL{
public:
stackLL();
void push(int x);
int pop();
void print();

private:
llNode* head;
};
```

Here's the member function definition:

```
int stackLL::pop(){
    if (head == NULL){
    return false;
    }

    else {
    llNode *tmp= new llNode;
    cout<<"The integer is: "<<head -> data;
    tmp = head;
    head = tmp -> next;
    delete tmp;
    return tmp -> data;

    }
}
```

Here's the implementation in main:

```
stackLL sll;
```

*couple lines down*

```
 sll.pop();
```

Comment: There is one more problem in your `pop()` implementation - memory leak.

Answer (score 5):

```
delete tmp;
return tmp -> data;
```

You are deleting `tmp` before returning the data. You are effectively returning data that does not exist or is already invalidated.
Dynamically allocating `tmp` is not necessary; you could just have `tmp` be allocated automatically (i.e. `llNode tmp = head;`). That would get rid of the segfault as well.

Additionally, the code for `pop` is probably not doing what you were intending it to do (or at least, it is not doing what a pop function for a linked list would do).

Besides, you should never use blank `new` or `delete` (it is prone to errors). Instead, use one of the smart pointers, preferably `std::unique_ptr<...>` (`ùnique_ptr` does not have a reference counter)

Answer (score 3):

Are you surprised it seg fault?

```
delete tmp;
return tmp -> data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in pop() function before returing the temp->data, you are actually deleting that temp node. That is the reason that you are getting segmentation fault.